# Docker: subnet clients can't ping other subnet

Tags: networking, docker

I have created a small network with 2 clients and 2 routers with this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y vim iputils-ping iproute2
```

The containers were created with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo docker build -t test02 .

sudo docker network create --internal --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 tunnel

sudo docker network create --internal --subnet=172.16.1.0/24 B1
sudo docker network create --internal --subnet=172.16.2.0/24 B2

sudo docker run --name R1 --hostname R1 --cap-add=ALL --net tunnel --ip="192.168.1.100" -dit test02

sudo docker run --name R2 --hostname R2 --cap-add=ALL --net tunnel --ip="192.168.1.200" -dit test02

sudo docker network connect --ip="172.16.1.254" B1 R1
sudo docker network connect --ip="172.16.2.254" B2 R2

sudo docker exec R1 ip route del default via 172.16.1.1

sudo docker exec R2 ip route del default via 172.16.2.1

sudo docker exec R1 ip route add 172.16.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.200

sudo docker exec R2 ip route add 172.16.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.100

sudo docker run --name PC1 --hostname PC1 --cap-add=ALL --net B1 --ip="172.16.1.2" -dit test02

sudo docker run --name PC2 --hostname PC2 --cap-add=ALL --net B2 --ip="172.16.2.2" -dit test02

sudo docker exec PC1 ip route del default via 172.16.1.1

sudo docker exec PC1 ip route add default via 172.16.1.254

sudo docker exec PC2 ip route del default via 172.16.2.1

sudo docker exec PC2 ip route add default via 172.16.2.254
```

Everything is fine, but `PC1` can't ping `PC2`. This is not an issue in `lxc`, where doing the same network configuration, `PC1` and `PC2` can communicate.

Why does this happen?

Docker version: `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`

**Update:**

Still without good results (I don't know if there's a configuration I'm missing)

Docker version: `Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command:

```
sudo docker network create --internal --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 tunnel
```

creates a bridge that can't communicate with other networks (`man docker-network-create`):

> ```
>    --internal[=false]
>        Restrict external access to the network
> ```

Leaving this option for all the subnets makes the networks accessible.